# vscode debug typescript compiled in docker container unbound breakpoint

Tags: typescript, docker, visual-studio-code

Most of the debugging recipes for VSCode + Typescript + Docker that I've seen assume that one is mounting the `dist/` folder as a container volume. I'm mounting the `src/` folder only and compiling the Typescript inside the container, and I'm not quite sure how that would affect my `launch.json` configuration. Am I missing something from my config given that I only compile inside the container? Can VSCode even support this? The docs aren't super clear about it.

My `npm start` script:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc --build tsconfig.json && tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./dist/index.js\""
  } 
}
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [ "./src/**/*" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

My `launch.json` debugger config:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "address": "localhost",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/path/in/container",
      "restart": true,
      "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "!**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I start the debugger, it appears to attach (I get container logs in the debug console), but then my breakpoints are always unbound, so I'm not sure if it's a problem related to my mount/compile setup, or if that's fine but VSCode is just not able to bind the breakpoints.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: Having more or less the same issue

Comment: Haven't solved this yet, but I also haven't had the time recently to dig into it. More investigation needed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you expose **port 9229** from your docker container?
Here's an example of my docker-compose file.

```
api:
  container_name: api
  hostname: my_cool_api
  env_file:
    - .env
  depends_on:
    - postgres
  build:
    context: ./api
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
  ports:
      - 3005:3005
      - 9229:9229
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./api:/api
```